# Corona SDK InAPP restoration and cancel misleading phenomena

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, coronasdk, restore

I'm having an issue with my corona SDK InApp testing(iOS only). I've a page to purchase a character. First time if I buy a product, it is working good. But if I do the following steps:

- Remove the app from the device
- Click cancel button in the `buy-cancel` alert (fig1.1). This will trigger: `event.transaction.state == "cancelled"`. (This cancel click is just done for explaining triggering case, that I am describing below)
- Then I came back to the scene again and clicking the buy button of fig 1.1, It will show an alert as in fig 1.2. I think it means it will automatically restore the app. But above all my expectation, it triggered the same method, that is: `event.transaction.state == "cancelled"`.

[image] Fig 1.1

[image] Fig 1.2

**Problem:** I am unlocking the item by writing it to a file when it is either `purchased/restored`. I think, when I reinstall the app, restoration has to be take place. But it is triggering `cancelled`. So how can I unloack the item. Pls, pls help me. Any suggestion is valuable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the store transaction wasn't finished properly the first time.

Did you make sure to call the following code in your transaction callback ? Even if the transaction is cancelled you need to finish it to let the store system know that you have processed the cancel:

```
store.finishTransaction( transaction )
```

Comment: Hi Teddy, first of all, thanks for the response. But I've mentioned it in my question that, first time my transaction was succeeded and it triggered "purchased", hence I was able to write it locally and unlocked the character. thanks.

Comment: Ok no problem. Could you please paste your code in the question so that we have a bit more details for troubleshooting ? ^^

Comment: Mine is same as that included inside corona's sample `InAppPurchase` code. Even their sample has the same issue... :(

Comment: My understanding is that the 'Cancelled' status is more like when an user has already purchased an item, and wants to cancel that purchase for some reason. So in your case it would make sense that the restore only notes the 'cancelled' and not the 'purchase' + 'cancelled' since the 'cancelled' event erases the 'purchase' event whatsoever, in the way CoronaSDK handles it at least.

Comment: Yes you perfectly got it. So in my case, how do I get the callback as 'purchase+cancelled' or 'already purchased'?

Comment: That's what i mean, if you receive in restore a cancelled, it means it was purchase+cancelled :) it means it was purchased first